# size_t i < _str.length creates endless loop in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, while-loop, size-t

I have a class (Array), see ctor below. I want to create the method Array::read(_str) to give an object of Array the array typed in the interface. (for example string _str = "1 2 3")

To determine the number of doubles the string should be converted into, I am counting the amount of spaces. The spaces are found correctly, but the loop does not end after the last space. (see output screen text).

> Why does the loop not end after finding both spaces ??

ctor Array

```
Array::Array(int _size)
{
    //ctor
    length = _size ;
    myArray = new double[length] ; // initialize array

    //default initialization
    for(size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        myArray[i] = i ;
    }
}
```

method Array::read(string _str)

```
void Array::read(string _str)
{
    // string_t find (<what to search>, <starting pos>) const ;

    // determine length (number of numbers)
    length = 0 ;
    int steps = 0 ;
    size_t i = 0 ;

    cout<<"Value of _str.length() : "<<_str.length() <<endl ; // test

    while( i < _str.length() && steps < 100)
    {

        // search for space starting it i
        i = _str.find(" ",i ) ;
        if(i!=string::npos) // npos is greatest possible size_t
            cout<<"_ found at: 1 =  "<< i <<endl ;

        length ++ ;     // new number present
        i ++ ;          // next time start after space
        steps ++ ;      // to prevent endless loop
    }
    cout<<endl<<steps ;

    delete[] myArray ; // free old array
    myArray = new double[length] ; // allocate space

    // fill with doubles


}
```

output screen text

```
Value of _str.length() : 5
_ found at: i = 1
_ found at: i = 3
_found at: i = 1
_found at: i = 3
```

This is repeating until `100` , thus the loop is only ended by the steps condition.

Comment: Please show us how you use this `Array` object, preferably create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, the output you show doesn't match the code you show. And what output do you expect?

Comment: > Is there a way to check whether the input _str actually contains a number?

Comment: The [`std::stod` (and friends)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) function might be a good start. Can be used in a loop to extract space-delimited numbers from a string, while also validating that there *is* a valid number.

Answer (score 4):

[`string::npos`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/) is defined as greatest possible value of `size_t`.

```
const size_t npos = -1;
```

When you find no characters, `i` is equal to `npos`. You then add one to it, and it overflows, becoming `0`.

As a solution, try this:

```
if (i != string::npos) {
    // ...
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to break the loop if `string::find` returns a `string::npos`:

```
while( i < _str.length() && steps < 100)
    {

        // search for space starting it i
        i = _str.find(" ",i ) ;
        if(  i==string::npos )
            break;
        else // npos is greatest possible size_t
            cout<<"_ found at: 1 =  "<< i <<endl ;

        length ++ ;     // new number present
        i ++ ;          // next time start after space
        steps ++ ;      // to prevent endless loop
    }
```

Comment: maybe use `else`?

Comment: well, I mean `if(i!=string::npos)` => `else`.

Comment: Oh, remove `if(i!=string::npos)` entirely is cleaner

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that if I change the loop to:

```
while( i < _str.length() && steps < 100)
    {

        // search for space starting it i
        i = _str.find(" ",i ) ;
        if(i!=string::npos) // npos is greatest possible size_t
        {
            cout<<"_ found at: 1 =  "<< i <<endl ;
            length ++;
            i ++ ;          // next time start after space
        }


        steps ++ ;      // to prevent endless loop
    }
```

The function does give the right result. (3 steps , 2 spaces found)
Thank you for the quich responses!